# Filtering out values of a bidimensional array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a bidimensional array which looks like this:

```
[[10, 20, 30, S1]
[10, 20, 30, S1]
[10, 20, 30, S1]
[50, 70, 80, G1]
[50, 70, 80, G1]
[50, 70, 80, G1]]
```

I want to filter out every "non-first" occurence of the 4th value of each sub-array, like this:

```
[[10, 20, 30, S1]
[10, 20, 30]
[10, 20, 30]
[50, 70, 80, G1]
[50, 70, 80]
[50, 70, 80]]
```

How is this possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume S1 and G1 are strings?

Comment: Can you please provide some information about what you have tried and/or have so far?

Comment: There should be commas after every array in the array except the last:
`[[10, 20, 30, S1],
[10, 20, 30, S1],
[10, 20, 30, S1],
[50, 70, 80, G1],
[50, 70, 80, G1],
[50, 70, 80, G1]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an object to keep track of the found values, and remove the last item from the subarrays when it was found before:

```
var items = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var id = arr[i][arr[i].length - 1];
  if (items.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    arr[i].pop();
  } else {
    items[id] = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same solution in mind (though with `if (items[id])` and `splice` instead of `pop`) but yours is more robust and elegant. +1